# How do I find the hour with most rides taken?

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataset below regarding the start time commuters book a car. I'd like to

1. create a function to discretise all bookings into their respective hours,
2. and find the hour (in AM/PM format) with the most bookings

The pandas dataframe looks like this:

| BookingID | RideStart |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | 2022-01-01 00:07:52.943 |
| 02 | 2022-01-01 00:09:31.745 |
| 03 | 2022-01-01 00:14:37.187 |
| 04 | 2022-01-02 00:18:09.127 |

Desired output:
`printf("{x} am/pm is the the hour with the highest bookings made")`

I tried the pd.grouper method but it dosent work, with an error `"Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'RangeIndex".`

Would really appreciate your help to solve this, thank you!

Comment: Where is bookings column? And also please post minimal reproducible data and desired output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pd.DatetimeIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html) for this. And then apply [`s.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html#), followed by [`s.idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmax.html):

```
import pandas as pd

# just adding a couple of different hours
data = {'BookingID': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4},
 'RideStart': {0: '2022-01-01 00:07:52.943',
  1: '2022-01-01 18:09:31.745',
  2: '2022-01-01 18:14:37.187',
  3: '2022-01-02 19:18:09.127'}}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

   BookingID                RideStart
0          1  2022-01-01 00:07:52.943
1          2  2022-01-01 18:09:31.745
2          3  2022-01-01 18:14:37.187
3          4  2022-01-02 19:18:09.127

max_hour = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['RideStart']).hour.value_counts().idxmax()
print(f'{max_hour%12} {"pm" if max_hour>12 else "am"} is the hour with the highest bookings made')

6 pm is the hour with the highest bookings made
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `pd.grouper` method, pandas already has tools for resampling values based on Datetime. The problem is, the dataframe doesn't currently have Datetime values, just strings. You can use the `pd.to_datetime()` method as described in [this tutorial](https://cumsum.wordpress.com/2022/02/26/pandas-typeerror-only-valid-with-datetimeindex-timedeltaindex-or-periodindex-but-got-an-instance-of-index/), and then downsample your data to the hour.

```
>>> a = ['2022-01-01 00:07:52.943',
    '2022-01-01 00:09:31.745',
    '2022-01-01 01:12:37.187',
    '2022-01-01 02:45:42.834',
    '2022-01-01 02:56:58.152']

>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data=a)
>>> print(df.head())
                         0
0  2022-01-01 00:07:52.943
1  2022-01-01 00:09:31.745
2  2022-01-01 01:12:37.187
3  2022-01-01 02:45:42.834
4  2022-01-01 02:56:58.152

>>> df.index = pd.to_datetime(df[0])
>>> df.resample('H').count()[0] # [0] is to get rid of extra, all-containing column
0   
2022-01-01 00:00:00 2
2022-01-01 01:00:00 1
2022-01-01 02:00:00 2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can make assumptions about the string length for the dates. You can do something like the following where you parse the hr from the date into a new column then just get the `mode`.

Note that I used a for loop at the end in case several hours are the mode.

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
    ['01','2022-01-01 00:07:52.943'],
    ['02','2022-01-01 00:09:31.745'],
    ['03','2022-01-01 00:14:37.187'],
    ['04','2022-01-02 00:18:09.127'],
    ['05','2022-01-02 00:18:09.130']
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['BookingID','RideStart'])

print(df)
print('---\n---')
# BEGIN SOLUTION

df['RideStartHr'] = df['RideStart'].str[14:16]

print(df)

modeList = df['RideStartHr'].mode().values

print('Mode(s):', modeList)

if len(modeList) > 1:
    print('There are {} most frequent hours. Listing all of them.'.format(len(modeList)))

for mode in modeList:
    hr = int(mode) % 12
    ampm = 'am' if mode <= '12' else 'pm'
    print('{} {} is a most frequent hour.'.format(hr, ampm))
```